# How to use class method output in view?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a class method find_all_media in model abc.rb. Model xyz and abc has relationship,

```
abc :has_many xyzs and

xyz :belongs_to abc

def self.find_all_media(media_name)

  if self.media_name == self.xyz.media_name
    return media_name
 end
end
```

I want to call this method in

```
 ### xyz/index view file
<% @abc.xyzs.each do |xyz| %>
<tr>
  <td><%=h xyz.media_name %></td>
  <td><%=h xyz.type %></td>
  <td>I want to call method find all_media here ?? </td>
```

I tried but not working, any  suggestions??

Comment: You have to do Model.find_all_media BUT the view isn't the place to get data. Do it in your controller.

Comment: I did like in abc_controller.rb @media = Xyz.find_all_media(author_name) and I use @media in view but it errors out.

Answer (score 0):

From your view code and the state you maintain, looks like you need an instance method and not class method.

```
def find_all_media(media_name)
   return media_name if self.media_name == self.xyz.media_name
end
```

Comment: I agree with @apnreadiving. You should be calling this in the controller and not directly in the view

Comment: This is my code                                                                def self.find_all_media(url, media_name)
    foo = Xyz.find_by_media_name_and_url(media_name,url)
    return foo[0] if !foo.blank?
    nil
  end   how i can use out from this method in view???

Answer (score 0):

I can see a problem in your class method, you have written it as class method and trying to access the instance methods in it i.e. media_name and xyz.media_name. so make it instance method as rc suggested.

```
<% @abc.xyzs.each do |xyz| %>
<tr>
  <td><%=h xyz.media_name %></td>
  <td><%=h xyz.type %></td>
  <td><% @abc.find_all_media(xyz.media_name) %></td> # calling find_all_media
```

Comment: Hi tried when I do @abc.find_all_media , @abc does not recognize method i guess it is a class method??

Comment: yes, here I suggested to create it instance method and use it.

Comment: Is there way to use as class method not by creating instance method.